# How to create a splash activity with kotlin in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, thread-sleep

I am trying to create a splash activity in my android app. On the beginning of the app, I want the app to stay in splash activity for 2 seconds and go to main activty. The splash activity only contains the app icon. Here's the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".views.SplashActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the `SplshActivity.kt` :

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        goToMain()
    }

    private fun goToMain() {
         Thread.sleep(2000)
        val i = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(i)
    }
}
```

Splash Activity is going to Main Activity after 2 seconds correctly. But, the problem is that when i run the app, splash activity is blank. Imageview is missing from the activity. I tried putting the `goToMain()` in `onStart()` and `onResume()`. Still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to see imageview in preview?

Comment: yes.. It disappears while running. I think there is some problem with `Thread.sleep()`. I think it puts the activity to sleep before loading the UI.

Comment: Then instead of thread use Handler.postDelayed for the same

Comment: Please share your image as well if you still having problem

Comment: I used `Handler.postDelayed` and problem solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer in kotlin :

```
Handler().postDelayed({
            val mIntent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(mIntent)
            finish()
        }, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Kindly check below code, You cannot able to finish activity before starting new one.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intenr = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intenr);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 2000L);
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Your code of SplashScreen in Kotlin

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
           startActivity(Intent(this@SplashScreen,MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }, /*time delay in milliseconds for eg 2000*/)
```

Comment: this answer should up at top

Answer (score 0):

**Launch activity**

*Global variable*

```
 val activityScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)


 activityScope.launch {
            delay(3000)

            var intent = Intent(this@CoroutinesSplashActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
```

**Prevention from the crash and leakage**

```
override fun onPause() {
        activityScope.cancel()
        super.onPause()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> and with timerTask kotlin

```
        Timer().schedule(700)
        {
            val mIntent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(mIntent)
            finish()
        }
```